# Is there a way to restore a previous version of file in vim

Tags: plugin

I had a `swp` file with old content, to which I restored and wasted much cleaning it. So I would like much such feature.

Jetbrains's IDEs have feature `local history`:

[image]

Which preserve history for specified settings, it looks this:
[image]

I would like similar feature in vim, maybe with plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you give some context (the situation you are in) and what you want to achieve. You could also explain what you have tried and how it fails.

Comment: You may want to check persistent undo files. Also you can of course restore from older swap files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mbbill/undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) plugin provides you similar feature provided that you have enabled the support for undofiles

see screenshot:

[image: undotree screenshot]

Here is what I have in my `.vimrc` files to control the support

```
" Save undo trees in files (such that they are available after vim is closed)
set undofile

" folder to store the undo files (the folder has to be created first)
" Save undo files in the .undo sub-folder (if it exists)
" Otherwise in the ~/vimfiles/undo folder (if it exists)
" It avoid to pollute your local folder
if has('win32')
  if !isdirectory(s:vim_data_folder .. 'undo')
    call mkdir(s:vim_data_folder .. 'undo')
  endif
  exe 'set undodir=' .. '.undo/,' .. s:vim_data_folder_alt .. 'undo/'
endif

if has('unix')
  if !isdirectory($HOME .. '/.vim/undo')
    call mkdir($HOME .. "/.vim/undo", "p", 0700)j
  endif
  set undodir=.undo/,~/.vim/undo/
endif

" Set the number of undo saved:
set undolevels=10000
```